# JSON object passing WCF and Android

Tags: android, json, wcf, parsing, post

Here is the client side Android ***MainActivity.java*** file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONStringer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("oncreate ", "girdi");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);

        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        Button sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFSolution/Service1/Check");
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Build JSON string
            JSONStringer userJson=null;
            try {
                userJson = new JSONStringer()
                    .object()
                       .key("user")
                          .object()
                         .key("Username").value(username.getText().toString())                                                                                                                                                        
                         .key("Password").value(password.getText().toString())                                                     
                         .key("Name").value(password.getText().toString())
                          .endObject()
                       .endObject();
                Log.e("json", "json created");
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            StringEntity entity=null;
            try {
                entity = new StringEntity(userJson.toString(),"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                                                
            entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            entity.setContentType("application/json");

            request.setEntity(entity);

            // Send request to WCF service
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            try {
                Log.e("response", "connect");
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

                Log.e("response","response get"+response.toString());
                //System.out.println(response.toString());


                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                String json = reader.readLine();

                Log.e("json string","test "+json.toString()+" lazım");
                System.out.println(json);
                //JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
                //JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);


            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

***Server side:***

***App.config:***

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <configuration>

          <appSettings>
            <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
          </appSettings>
          <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true"/>
          </system.web>
          <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
          app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
          <system.serviceModel>
             <services>
                 <service name="MyWCFSolution.Service1">
                     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyWCFSolution.IService1">
                          <identity>
                              <dns value="localhost"/>
                          </identity>
                      </endpoint>
                      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                      <host>
                          <baseAddresses>
                              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFSolution/Service1/"/>
                          </baseAddresses>
                      </host>
                 </service>
             </services>
             <behaviors>
                 <serviceBehaviors>
                      <behavior>
<!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
<!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
set the value below to true. Set to false before deployment 
to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
                      </behavior>
                 </serviceBehaviors>
             </behaviors>
        </system.serviceModel>
        <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

***Service.cs:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyWCFSolution
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string CheckSQL(string getJSON)
        {
            string jsonConverted;
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serialize = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            User X = new User();
            User Y = new User();
            User Z = new User();
            opUser operate = new opUser();
            X.AutoID = 1;
            X.Name = "abc";
            X.Password = "12345";
            X.Surname = "ab";
            X.Username = "cde";
            jsonConverted = serialize.Serialize(X);
            Y = (User)serialize.Deserialize(jsonConverted, typeof(User));
            Z = operate.GetUser(Y);
            jsonConverted = serialize.Serialize(Z);
            return "asdf";
        }
    }
}
```

***IService.cs:***

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.Text;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;


    namespace MyWCFSolution
    {

        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IService1
        {
            [OperationContract]
            string CheckSQL(User user);

        }
    }
```

***User.cs:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace MyWCFSolution
{

    public class User
    {
        private Int64 _AutoID;
        private string _Username;
        private string _Password;
        private string _Name;
        private string _Surname;

        public Int64 AutoID { get { return _AutoID; } set { _AutoID = value; } }
        public string Username { get { return _Username; } set { _Username = value; } }
        public string Password { get { return _Password; } set { _Password = value; } }
        public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; } }
        public string Surname { get { return _Surname; } set { _Surname = value; } }
    }

    public class UserList : CollectionBase
    {
        public User this[int index]
        {
            get { return this.List[index] as User; }
        }
        public void Add(User obj)
        {
            this.List.Add(obj);
        }
        public int IndexOf(User obj)
        {
            return this.List.IndexOf(obj);
        }
    }

}
```

***opUser.cs:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace MyWCFSolution
{
    public class opUser
    {
        public User GetUser(User UserD)
        {
            UserList Result = new UserList();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = Connection.ConnectToSql();
            User temp = new User();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCommSelect = new SqlCommand("dbo.spSelectUserByPassword", conn);
                sqlCommSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] { 
                    new SqlParameter("@Username",UserD.Username ),                   
                    new SqlParameter("@Password",UserD.Password )
                };
                sqlCommSelect.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);


                SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommSelect.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    temp.Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);
                    temp.Surname = Convert.ToString(dr["Surname"]);

                }
                dr.Close();
                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                conn.Close();
                Result = null;

            }
            return temp;
        }

    }
}
```

***Here is the LogCat In Eclipse for Running Android App:***

01-11 22:50:43.344: E/oncreate(457): girdi
01-11 22:50:48.955: W/KeyCharacterMap(457): No keyboard for id 0
01-11 22:50:48.955: W/KeyCharacterMap(457): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-11 22:50:50.935: E/json(457): json created
01-11 22:50:50.944: E/response(457): connect
01-11 22:50:51.164: E/response(457): response getorg.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@405722d0
01-11 22:50:51.174: W/System.err(457): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at com.example.logapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:95)
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4257)
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4566)
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1280)
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3855)
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
01-11 22:50:51.184: W/System.err(457): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
01-11 22:50:51.194: W/System.err(457): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
01-11 22:50:51.194: W/System.err(457): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
01-11 22:50:51.194: W/System.err(457): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1120)
01-11 22:50:51.194: W/System.err(457): at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
01-11 22:50:51.194: W/System.err(457): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1663)
01-11 22:50:51.194: W/System.err(457): at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2560)
01-11 22:50:51.194: W/System.err(457): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2535)
01-11 22:50:51.204: W/System.err(457): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
01-11 22:50:51.204: W/System.err(457): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 22:50:51.204: W/System.err(457): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-11 22:50:51.204: W/System.err(457): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-11 22:50:51.204: W/System.err(457): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 22:50:51.204: W/System.err(457): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-11 22:50:51.215: W/System.err(457): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-11 22:50:51.215: W/System.err(457): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-11 22:50:51.215: W/System.err(457): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

HTTP is executing. I mean, response is came from server but I cannot get the JSON data. I tried to write json data using `System.out.print` but didn't work. Http connection is working but can't get the JSON. Why is it happening? I am working a few days on this exception but didn't find. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

what is the output of the below line,

```
        Log.e("response","response get"+response.toString());
```

... Just check the responseCode for the http request, if the reponseCode is 200, then you are good,

```
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
        }
      } else {
        Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
      }
```

I believe the response code could be different,thats why you are not seeing json response

Comment: response code is usually 3 digit codes, I am not sure why you are getting 5 digit codes.

Comment: You can download a tool called fiddler and analyze all the traffic from android emulator to server. Even that tool helps you to find the exact issue.

Comment: Is there any other solution? I will try to find the exact issue. Do you have any example about this problem?

Comment: And here is the answer of your question(I wrote in the question) org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@405722d0

Comment: Are you sure about the response code?  Did you put some logs in the catch block to make sure there is no exception to make sure that we didnt miss.

Comment: Thank you. I will examine this website.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22610/discussion-between-metalfrekans-and-ramesh-sangili)

Comment: JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("username", username);
jsonObj.put("apikey", apikey);
// Create the POST object and add the parameters
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType("application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);